# javascript click function not working on form generated in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, click

I have a form created using echo command in php. It is being displayed correctly. I have a javascript which detects click on radio button of form and displays the hyperlink/anchor corresponding to each button group, which is not working.

But if I create the form in html only without any php, it works perfectly. please HELP.

Form creation

```
echo("<form name ='input' action = 'result.php' method = 'POST'>");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    echo(($i+1)." ".$row[1]."<br>");
    echo("
    <input type = 'radio' value = $row[2] name = '$i'>$row[2]&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type = 'radio' value = $row[3] name = '$i'>$row[3]<br>
    <input type = 'radio' value = $row[4] name = '$i'>$row[4]&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type = 'radio' value = $row[5] name = '$i'>$row[5]&nbsp&nbsp
    <a id='$i' href='javascript:clear($i)'>Reset</a><br>");
    $i++;
    $z[]=$row[6];
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$('input:radio').click(function() { 
    var n = $(this).attr('name');
    var k ='#' + n;
    alert($(this).attr('name')); 
    $(k).show(400);
    });
```

Comment: what error are you getting in consol?

Comment: And the generated HTML sent to the browser would also be helpful.

Comment: try input[type=radio]

Comment: Try putting the html output. php's echo isn't your problem because that is interpreted in the server. In this code I can say. 1) Close the form. 2) quote the radio value. Those aren't errors per se but will show cleaner output

Comment: @ErikNedwidek this is the generated HTML sent to browser : http://pastebin.com/eNviPC09

Comment: @Edward no error in console

Comment: @WordPress "input" is the name of form

Comment: this works on jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/VrmpE/

Comment: I don't think we have enough information, PHP alone cannot interfere with JavaScript, if it was generated by AJAX then the problem would be different, can you post the HTML that works please?

Comment: I pasted your form from pastebin into Edwards JSfiddle and it worked. Not sure where to go from here as you also say there are no errors in the JavaScript console. I think you need to try whatever javascript debugger is available for your web browser.

Comment: @Edward here's the pure html code that worked : http://pastebin.com/fm230iqZ

But the problem's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click','input:radio',(function() { 
  var n = $(this).attr('name');
  var k ='#' + n;
  alert($(this).attr('name')); 
  $(k).show(400);
});
```

When clicking on dynamically created elements you need to use event delegation.

Comment: Form is generated server-side, there are no AJAX calls in the question, why do you think it is dynamically created?

Comment: Not if it was generated using php, AJAX maybe but not php alone.

Comment: Only because he said that his same jquery was working in pure html. `But if I create the form in html only without any php` so I assumed that maybe the php was being shown after the document was initially loaded.

Comment: That would lead me to believe that something is wrong with his html generation via php and not his java script then.

Comment: Great, If your html body is really big i.e. contains more then just your form I would recommend surrounding your `form` by a `div` and doing `$('#yourDivID').on('click','input:radio'..` etc.. so that its just listening on your div for clicks and not the whole body. It would improve performance on large html files.  Note: the div would need to be part of your original html and not generated by your php.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing `$('input:radio')` to `$('input[type="radio"]')`.

Try this

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() { 
    var n = $(this).attr('name');
    var k ='#' + n;
    alert($(this).attr('name')); 
    $(k).show(400);
});
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit more about the difference between those two selectors?

Comment: The difference in those selectors is that the second uses the [attribute=value]. The : is used with pseudo classes and radio is not a pseudo class. Examples of pseudo classes are input:first-child, input:focus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... your problem is that `$row` array should be with curly brackets because you're in double quotes

```
echo("<form name ='input' action = 'result.php' method = 'POST'>");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    echo(($i+1)." ".$row[1]."<br>");
    echo("
    <input type = 'radio' value = '{$row[2]}' name = '$i'>{$row[2]}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type = 'radio' value = '{$row[3]}' name = '$i'>{$row[3]}<br>
    <input type = 'radio' value = '{$row[4]}' name = '$i'>{$row[4]}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type = 'radio' value = '{$row[5]}' name = '$i'>{$row[5]}&nbsp&nbsp
    <a id='$i' href='javascript:clear($i)'>Reset</a><br>");
    $i++;
    $z[]=$row[6];
}
```

Comment: This would have flagged Encaps error, OP didn't show any error.